# JSF Bean getting called twice on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, primefaces, jsf-2.2, weblogic12c, backing-beans

My JSF bean getting called twice on IE11. But the same program running properly, when I use FireFox and Chrome. I have done the deployment on Oracle Weblogic. I using ViewScoped to keep the bean keep alive till webpage is active.

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "callingBean", eager = true)
    @ViewScoped
    public class CallingBean implements Serializable 

   <h:head>
   <title>JSF DEMO</title>
   <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
   </h:head>
   <h:body style="font-size: 12px">
   <p:layout fullPage="true">
   <p:layoutUnit position="center" rendered="#{callingBean.username != null}">
```

Below is web.xml for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>JSF_Demo</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>8192</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xhtml</extension>
    <mime-type>application/xhtml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What did you debug? Checked network traffic?

Comment: When I deploy the same war file on Apache Tomcat, it works for all the browsers.

Comment: weblogic is java-ee and already contains jsf libraries. Tomcat does not. 100% identical war without additional config in weblogic results in undefined behaviour regarding classloading.

Comment: Agreed. But its should behave same for all browsers. right?

Comment: Not when there is, in other areas, an (maybe unintentional) undefined behaviour. And I'm not saying this IS the case, but debugging (double actions in browser console? or other things) might help. Oh and to exclude other things, please always make a [mcve] and post version and implementation info (both jsf and primefaces)